# How to turn off color legend in a ggplot stacked bar graph? all solutions have failed

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a stacked bar graph and ggplot has automatically generated a color legend that I want to remove. I have tried show.legend=FALSE, theme(legend.position="none"), and guides(colour=FALSE) and none of those solutions have removed the legend. I'll include the code below.

```
ggplot(unique_per_day, aes(fill=Entity.Name,y=prop, x=Entity.Type, width = org.count, label=Entity.Name), show.legend=FALSE) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", colour= "black") + 
    facet_grid(~Entity.Type, scales="free_x", space="free_x" ) +
    theme(legend.position="none", panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "npc")) +
    guides(colour=FALSE) +
    geom_text(size = 2.4, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    theme_void()
```

[image: example_1.png]

Comment: Have you tried setting `theme(legend.position="none")` after `theme_void()`?

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to troubleshoot if you provided an example dataset (e.g. `dput(unique_per_day)`), but my guess is that you need to remove the "fill" aesthetic, instead of the "color" aesthetic, e.g.

```
ggplot(unique_per_day, aes(fill=Entity.Name,y=prop, x=Entity.Type, width = org.count, label=Entity.Name)) + 
    geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity", colour= "black", show.legend=FALSE) + 
    facet_grid(~Entity.Type, scales="free_x", space="free_x" ) +
    guides(fill = FALSE) +
    geom_text(size = 2.4, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
    theme_void() +
    theme(legend.position="none", panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "npc"))
```

### Edit

Here is an example using the "palmerpenguins" example dataset:

With the original code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(palmerpenguins)

penguins %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  filter(island == "Dream") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = species, y = 1, fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  facet_grid(~ island, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  theme(legend.position = "none", panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "npc")) +
  guides(colour = FALSE) +
  theme_void()
```

[image: example_1.png]

With "theme_void" moved above "theme":

```
penguins %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  filter(island == "Dream") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = species, y = 1, fill = sex)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
  facet_grid(~ island, scales = "free_x", space = "free_x") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position="none", panel.spacing.x = unit(0, "npc"))
```

[image: example_2.png]